# como puedo restar los valores de un diccionario en python

Tags: python

Quiero restar valores de un mismo diccionario de la siguiente manera:

```
vec=[400,20,1,65]
```

Quiero restar así: `=  vec[400,20,1,65] - [400,400,20,1]`;
es decir, el primer valor menos el primer valor del diccionario, el segundo valor menos el primer valor del array, luego el tercer valor con el segundo valor y el cuarto valor con el tercer valor: trato de usar dos ciclos FOR:

```
vec=[]
for vector in productoslinea:
    vec.append(vector[i])
cont=len(vec)
for linea in productoslinea:
     vec[cont]-vec[cont-1]
```

Comment: En python no existen los arreglos (arrays), además no se ve ningún diccionario por tu código. Creo que debes usar la terminología correcta, si no es muy difícil entender tu pregunta. haz `print(type(vec))`, verás que `vec` es una lista.

Comment: vec=[]
            self.env.cr.execute(consulta_product)
            productoslinea = [j for j in self.env.cr.fetchall()]
            for vector in productoslinea:
                vec.append(vector[2])
            cont=len(vec)
            for linea in productoslinea:
                sheet.write('F', vec[cont]-vec[cont-1], letter4G)

Comment: lo que trato es restar un indice con un indice menor, mi pregunta es demasiada compleja para describirlo amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los puedes restar usando comprensión de listas. Como tú dijiste, cada elemento del resultado es la resta de dos elementos:

```
resultado[i] = vector1[i] - vector2[1]
```

que se traduce casi directo a una comprensión de lista

```
resultado = [vector1[i] - vector2[i] for i in range(len(vector1))]
```

sólo faltaba agregar un `for` que recorre los indices válidos.

**Demo**

```
vector1=[400,20,1,65]
vector2=[400,400,20,1]

resultado= [vector1[i] - vector2[i] for i in range(len(vector1))]
print(resultado)
```

produce

```
[0, -380, -19, 64]
```

Comment: gracias, mi unico problema es que no uso dos listas sino uno.